# How much space does Apportable take…

Tags: apportable

I have an App that is 49.9 MB.  I am going to convert it to Apportable.

I need it to be under 50MB for Google Play…

So what is the maximum size the app can be plus the Apportable conversion…

Anotherwards how much space does Apportable take…  So I know how much stuff I should delete from my apple app.

Comment: You know it when you built it. This isn't something you will get an exact info on without trying it with your specific app. There's too many parameters influencing this, from compiler flags to build settings to apportable version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the apportable platform normally is around 6mb additional space in a release build in most APKs. That is compressed and it may be different from app to app.